# How to debug remote JVM exposed by ngrok tunnel

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, ngrok, tunnel

I have a java process on one of my machines listening on port 4502. I have created a tunnel using ngrok so that I can access the application on my development machine. The issue I'm facing is attaching a debugger to the remote JVM.

Here is the debug java configuration I'm using:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:5005,server=y,suspend=n`

Here is the ngrok configuration for the tunnel to the application:

`ngrok http 4502`

Here is the ngrok configuration for the tunnel to the JVM (I have also tried http protocol with no luck):

`ngrok tcp 5005`

ngrok outputs the following for the tcp tunnel:

`Forwarding tcp://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:10928 -> 127.0.0.1:5005`

Using IntelliJ, I configure the remote debugging like this:

```
Debugger mode: Attach to remote JVM
Host: tcp://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io
Port: 10928
```

I get the following error when starting the debugger:

**Error running 'Debug Author Desktop': Unable to open debugger port (tcp://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:10928): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"**

On the machine running the java process, I have made sure that the 5005 port is open before starting the process. On the machine using IntelliJ, I have made sure that the 10928 port is open. What must I do so that I can attach the debugger to the process running on my second machine? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have some kind of firewall between hosts. Can you ping it. If yes try "nc -zv 2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io 10928" on host you run your idea.

Comment: Using the ```nc -zv``` command I am able to ping successfully. The response is "Connection to 5.tcp.eu.ngrok.io port 14160 [tcp/*] succeeded!". When pinging using ```telnet <host> <ip>``` I get the following "Connected to 5.tcp.eu.ngrok.io." followed by "Connection closed by foreign host."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The issue was in the Remote Debugger configuration. When specifying the host, you must not include the protocol. Once I changed `tcp://2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io` to `2.tcp.eu.ngrok.io`, it worked!